# Enviar valores HTML a funcion PHP

Tags: php, html

hola quisiera saber la forma de como puedo ocupar los valores que le doy a un input ya sea de tipo number en este caso en un html y ocuparlos en una función de un archivo php, aclaro que en ese archivo php hay varias funciones.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo ideal seria saber si es un formulario y quieres hacerlo desde el `submit` de tu boton o bien, quisieras enviarlos mediante `ajax`.

En el primer caso tienes dos opciones mediante metodo `GET` y metodo `POST`

```
<form action="tu_archivo.php" method="post">
    Nombre usuario: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Email:  <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="¡Enviarme!" />
</form>
```

En el tag `action` va la ruta de tu archivo php, como mencionas que en ese mismo archivo hay varias funciones seria algo asi desde el PHP :

```
<?php
    $action = '';
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch ($action) {
            case 'login' : 
                login();
                break;
            case 'register' :
                register();
                break;
            ....
        }
    }
?>
```

Asi, obtienes la accion que se llamo y puedes llamar a tu funcion sin ningun problema y ya desde la funcion acceder a los valores :

```
function login() {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
}
```

En el segundo caso, puedes utilizar `ajax` y deberas incluir `jquery` a tu proyecto.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "tu_archivo.php",
    type : "POST",
    data: { username : 'test', 'action' : 'login' },
    ...
});
```

Funcionando de la misma manera.

Comment: el puto amo :D gracias

Comment: @SantySC jajaja saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recuperarlos en la página PHP destino, a través de las variables:

- $_GET[`<name`>]
- $_POST[`<name`>]

dependiendo del método que utilices en el encabezado del formulario (method='POST'/'GET').

`<name>`, es el mismo atributo que utilizaste al crear los objetos de formulario a los que te refieres.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es direcionar con tipos de metodos que exiten :

Ejemplo de solo 2

```
 <form action="registrar.php" method ="post">
 <form action="registrar.php" method ="get">
```

Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer,

tu pregunta es muy basica espero te ayude esto

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="PAGINA A LA QUE QUERES MANDAR LOS DATOS">
// VARIABLE 1 //
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE</label>
    <input type="TEXT, NUMBER, EL QUE NECESITES" class="form-control" 
 name="NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE">
  </div>
// VARIABLE 2 //
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE</label>
<input type="TEXT, NUMBER, EL QUE NECESITES" class="form-control" name="NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE">
</div>
// VARIABLE 3, ETC //
// CON UN BOTON TIPO SUBMIT ENVIAS LOS DATOS A LA OTRA PAGINA //
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ENVIAR</button>
  </form>
```

Y en la otra pagina las capturas:

```
<?php
$VARIABLE1 = $_POST['NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE 1'];
$VARIABLE2 = $_POST['NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE 2'];
$VARIABLE3 = $_POST['NOMBRE DE LA VARIABLE 3 ETC'];

// Y USAS LAS VARIABLES $VARIABLE1, $VARIABLE2, $VARIABLE3 DONDE NECESITES //
?>
```

Comment: No se si estaba implicito lo que pregunté pero de que manera envio esos valores a la funcion que necesito y solo ejecuto esa función?